# Adding and removing hours from current time creating infinite loop for datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using eonasdan Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker and I added 4 hours to defaultDate option. but when on change i am tring to remove these 4 hours from time its creating infinite loop and showing wrong date and time.

code is following

```
  var $datePickerOutput = $('#datePickerOutput'),
      d = moment();

  if ( $datePickerOutput.length ) {
    var defaults = {
      inline: true,
      sideBySide: true,
      useCurrent: false,
      defaultDate: d.add(3, 'hours'),
      minDate: d,
    };
    $datePickerOutput.datetimepicker(defaults);
    $datePickerOutput.on('dp.change', function(e){
      var $this = $(this);
      var presentDate  = new Date();
      var selectedDate = new Date(e.date);

      var pd = presentDate.getDate(),
          pm = presentDate.getMonth(),
          py = presentDate.getFullYear(),
          sd = selectedDate.getDate(),
          sm = selectedDate.getMonth(),
          sy = selectedDate.getFullYear();

      if ( ( pd+pm+py !== sd+sm+sy ) ) {
        console.log(moment(e.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A'));
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.subtract(4, 'hours'));
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, what does `pd+pm+py !== sd+sm+sy` mean? Note that the `date` method triggers [`dp.change`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) so your handler will be executed again and again until `pd+pm+py !== sd+sm+sy` becomes false.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out the current date. if the selected date isn't today's date then minus 3 hours from the time and show. that's what i am trying to do.. and i added this check because of that. please give me some solution if i am doing wrong. I am not very good with javascript

Comment: But the issue only starts when i add `.subtract(4, 'hours')` in the line `$(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.subtract(4, 'hours'));`

Comment: To check if selected date is on the same day of today you can use moment [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), in your case: `moment().isSame(e.date, 'day')`. Anyway, as I said before, setting a new date to the picker using [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method will trigger again `dp.change` event.

Comment: then how can i resolve this issue. I wanted to show 4 hour ahead in the time for today but when user select next date he/she would see the current date.